# How do I send multiple cookies in python3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, session, curl

example:

```
url: www.blabla.com    
headers ={ bla bla ...}  
data = { bla bla... Cookie:"asdasd", cookie:"fghkmfglh"} 
request.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

When I do this in my last post takes cookies 2 does not throw separately

Answer (score 0):

The protocol guide: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.5

In summary, you would put one cookie header and separate the values using ';'.
For example in the header:

`cookie: key1:value1;key2:value2;key3:value3`

Comment: cookie: JSESSIONID

Cookie: 404771338.47873.0000;

two cookies in data parameter , case sensitive, initial characters are different key names

Answer (score 0):

cookie: JSESSIONID

Cookie: 404771338.47873.0000;

two  cookies in data parameter  , case sensitive, initial characters are different key names